# Zener Diode Current Explanation

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, zener

What is the point of Zener Diode Current? I have to replace this [BZT52C8V2-7](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ds18004-1142534.pdf) Zener Diode with the current version [BZT52C8V2-7-F](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0003550684_1-2542352.pdf) and the Zener Current is 700 nA vs the previous 5mA. What effects would lowering my Zener current have on the circuit and how would I fix this if this would cause an issue?[image]

Comment: Where are you getting 700 nA? Are you looking at the below-threshold reverse current \$I_R\$? The Zener test current \$I_{ZT}\$ is still 5 mA.

Comment: See their side comparison, I am asking about the Zener Current.

Comment: @WesEllgass I’d bet that’s a mistake.

Comment: Both of your datasheet links go to the same document, Diodes Inc document number DS18004 Rev 38 - 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, always refer to the [data sheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds18004.pdf) numbers: -

[image]

As you can see, the test current that establishes the Zener voltage (typically 8.2 volts) is 5 mA and, the 700 nA figure refers to the leakage current when only 5 volts is applied.

Yes, the table in your question is in error.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is only in how the term is used in each list, they refer to different things.

5 mA was the test current, meaning what current was used while measuring other paramaters, while 700 nA was leakage current below zener voltage. Compare the graphs to see actual performance.

Usually term *Zener current* would refer to the reverse current needed for the reverse voltage to be at desired level. I think they have made a mistake, but of course they could use the term as they wish.

Answer (score 0):

Supplier catalogs are collected data, not primary sources.  The datasheet is a primary source, and should be relied upon as such, unless heard otherwise from the manufacturer.  (It is prudent to check with the manufacturer to see if the datasheet has been updated, or what application notes or errata might be available for a given part, particularly complex devices such as ICs.)

The datasheets show identical information (you've seemingly failed to state a question).

The difference, then, is an error in the database.  Mistakes happen from time to time.  They can be reported to the supplier:

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/BZT52C8V2-7-F?qs=qwHcpYdfUbMnDjqva%252BUy%252BQ%3D%3D

[image]

Several suppliers have such systems in place to streamline reporting and updating.